# java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit vs java.time.Duration for timeout arguments

Tags: java, java-8

When writing an API, I tend to define methods that take a *timeout* parameter as having arguments `long timeout, TimeUnit unit`.  This follows many `java.util.concurrent` methods that have the same requirement.

In Java 8, I've noticed the new `Duration` class in the `java.time` package, and wonder if I might as well define new methods as having a `Duration timeout` argument.

Advantage I can see from this are:

- It's is easier for users to write constants:

  ```
  private static final Duration ACQUIRE_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofMinutes(10);

  someResource.acquire(ACQUIRE_TIMEOUT);
  ```

  vs

  ```
  private static final long ACQUIRE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10);

  someResource.acquire(ACQUIRE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  ```

But here's a possible problem:

- How do users specify infinite time?

  ```
  someResource.acquire(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // No timeout
  ```

  vs

  ```
  someResource.acquire(Duration.ofSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE)); // Is this how it's done?
  ```

  where `acquire(Duration)` could be implemented as:

  ```
  public boolean acquire(Duration timeout) {
      long millis;
      try { millis = timeout.toMillis(); }
      catch (ArithmeticException ignore) { millis = Long.MAX_VALUE; } // yuck!

      ...
  }
  ```

  Definitely not the prettiest code.

Is there a better way of doing this?  Are there other gotchas or reasons I shouldn't use `java.time.Duration` for timeout arguments in APIs I provide?

Comment: Your first example using TimeUnit can also be written: `acquire(10, MINUTES);` with a static import, which is probably as readable as (if not more readable than) using a Duration. I also think that people used to the concurrency API would be less surprised with a TimeUnit than with a  Duration.

Comment: *Your first example using TimeUnit can also be written: acquire(10, MINUTES);* -> This is true, but I wanted to illustrate how one would declare the timeout as a constant at the top of the class.  (The only way I know how.  One could also add a second `TimeUnit` constant to define the unit, but that isn't much less clumsy.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code

```
private static final long ACQUIRE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10);
someResource.acquire(ACQUIRE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

counteracts the intended use of providing a value in an application specific unit together with that unit. The intended use should be `someResource.acquire(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);`

But it shows the problem with this approach as it is impossible to define a single constant bearing a value and a `TimeUnit`. So `Duration` has a point here.

Since `TimeUnit` is the well-known type created for concurrency APIs and used by the backend code in most cases, I would never omit the methods with the `(long,TimeUnit)` signature, but providing overloads accepting a `Duration` is not wrong.

---

When it comes to the “no timeout” question, most APIs don’t have a special treatment for `Long.MAX_VALUE`, regardless of whether it is provided as seconds or milliseconds. The observed “no timeout” behavior results from the fact that both quantities, `(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` and `(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` denote a time, none of today’s computers will survive. We can be happy if mankind lasts that long. Using `Long.MAX_VALUE-1` would exhibit the same behavior.

By the way, some concurrency tools unconditionally convert timeouts to the nanosecond scale internally, which implies that the maximum waiting time is limited to about 300 years “only”, but I assume that for most applications that still equals to “practically no timeout”.

In other words, there is no practical difference between `Duration.ofSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE)` and `Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` when used as a timeout in a runtime operation.

---

Addendum: I first overlooked your question regarding the practical implementation. I recommend to follow the behavior of converting to nanoseconds described above rather than using milliseconds. The best thing I can come up with is

```
public boolean acquire(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    // actual implementation
}
static final Duration MAX_WAIT = Duration.ofNanos(Long.MAX_VALUE);
public boolean acquire(Duration timeout) {
    return acquire(
        timeout.compareTo(MAX_WAIT)>=0? Long.MAX_VALUE: timeout.toNanos(),
        TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}
```

It would be possible to do a similar thing with milliseconds, however, I think in the future the imprecision of milliseconds over nanoseconds is more likely to become an issue than the maximum timeout being limited to something above 292 years.

Comment: *When it comes to the “no timeout” question, most APIs don’t have a special treatment for Long.MAX_VALUE* -> This is spot on.  I don't want to add special treatment in my implementation either, but there *is* a practical difference for `Duration.ofSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE)` that I can't so far get around: Even though `TimeUnit.toMillis()` clamps overflows to `Long.MAX_VALUE` making *no special treatment* possible, `Duration.toMillis()` throws `ArithmeticException`.  This, as it stands, makes `Duration` unappealing for use as a timeout variable.

Comment: In Java 11+ you can use [`TimeUnit#convert(Duration)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#convert(java.time.Duration)) which will not throw an `ArithmeticException` in case of overflow, opting to return `Long.MIN_VALUE` or `Long.MAX_VALUE` as appropriate. @antak

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be waiting for infinite time with a lock. There are other concurrency and inter thread signalling methods of locking and unlocking you should explore

java.time.Duration : Comes from Java 8 new Date and Time Api

java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit : Comes from Java concurrency package

If I am writing code associated with concurrency or Threads I would use TimeUnit but if I am writing code with manipulating Date, Time I am using Java 8 I would use java.time.Duration

Comment: *You shouldn't be waiting for infinite time with a lock* -> Waiting with a lock, yes.  Waiting *for* a lock, is more in line with what the question is asking.  I've updated the question to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I defined these constants:

```
/** The maximum value of {@link Duration} */
public static final Duration MAX_DURATION = Duration.ofSeconds(Long.MAX_VALUE, 999_999_999);

/** The maximum value of a duration convertible to nanoseconds */
public static final Duration MAX_NANO_DURATION = Duration.ofNanos(Long.MAX_VALUE);

/** A pseudo value denoting an infinite duration */
// The result is lower than MAX_DURATION, because MAX_DURATION can't be expressed as a single TimeUnit
public static final Pair<Long, TimeUnit> INFINTE_TIMEOUT = convertDurationToTimeUnit(MAX_DURATION);
```

And this method:

```
/**
 * Converts the given duration to an accurate pair of seconds or nanoseconds and the corresponding {@link TimeUnit}. If the duration can't be expressed in
 * nanoseconds, the returned value will be the seconds with stripped nanoseconds.
 * @param duration duration to convert
 * @return pair of seconds / nanoseconds and time unit ({@link TimeUnit#SECONDS} / {@link TimeUnit#NANOSECONDS})
 */
public static Pair<Long, TimeUnit> convertDurationToTimeUnit(Duration duration) {
    return duration.compareTo(Durations.MAX_NANO_DURATION) > 0
            ? Pair.of(duration.getSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            : Pair.of(duration.toNanos(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}
```

Use it:

```
public boolean await(Duration duration) throws InterruptedException {
    Pair<Long, TimeUnit> timeout = convertDurationToTimeUnit(duration);
    return signal.await(timeout.getLeft(), timeout.getRight());
}
```

... infinitely:

```
public boolean awaitInfinitely() throws InterruptedException {
    return signal.await(INFINTE_TIMEOUT.getLeft(), INFINTE_TIMEOUT.getRight());
}
```